# Jmeter using Ant test run fails with “Fatal error during transformation”

Tags: jmeter

Anyone suggest me how to override this issue

[Got an error when ran a test using Ant]
[1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynfMA.png

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code on Stack Overflow, not a link/url. Thanks.

Comment: I had attached screenshot its not link or url @Guillaume

Comment: The code should still be on Stack Overflow. Have a look at the link above please.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `neww.jtl` file is not a valid [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file and its turn most probably this is due to some custom [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)  so make sure to have at least this line in the `build.xml`

```
<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
```

Or even better take the original [build.xml](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/extras/build.xml) from vanilla JMeter distribution bundle and instead of modifying pass the desired .jmx script name via -D command-line argument like:

```
ant -Dtest=neww
```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)